# facebook app allows only one tab?

Tags: facebook

i have a business page ob facebook and i want to create 3 tabs for offers, best selling, promotions.
I have create on my website 3 pages without header and footer and show only the main content.

To do this

- I have create an app on facebook developers.
- i created my first custom facebook tab that show contents of my
  webpage which working fine.

When i tried to created another tab clicking add platform the Page Tab is grey meaning that i cant create another tab.

This means that the app can have only one tab ?

and if i want to have 2-3 custom tabs whats the solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This means that the app can have only one tab ?

Yes.

> and if i want to have 2-3 custom tabs whats the solution ?

To create 2-3 apps.